Lyapunov inequality for practical stability
Let $e := x-\hat{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ verify
$$ \dot{e} = (A-LC)e + F(x)-F(\hat{x}) + W$$
where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, C \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}, W\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $F$ is Lipschitz on compact sets.
Suppose that the pair $(A,C)$ is observable, that is, we can choose $L$ to impose any desired eigenvalues on the matrix $(A-LC)$.
My question: can we choose $L$ to make $e$ arbitrarily small when $t\to +\infty$ ?
My attempt: Let $\alpha>0$ be a constant to be chosen, and $P_{\alpha}=P_{\alpha}^\top >0$ be an $n\times n$ matrix solution to the Lyapunov inequality
$$ P_\alpha(A-LC)+(A-LC)^\top P_\alpha < -\alpha P_\alpha $$
Since $(A,C)$ is observable, we can always find a gain $L$ such that $P_\alpha$ exists. We consider then the Lyapunov function candidate
$$ V(e) := e^\top P e$$
Differentiating $V$ with respect to $t$, we find
$$ \dot{V} \leq - \alpha V + 2e^\top P_\alpha (F(x)-F(\hat{x})) + 2 e^\top P_\alpha W$$
Applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Young inequality, we get, for any $\epsilon > 0$,
$$ \dot{V} \leq (-\alpha + \epsilon)V + \frac{1}{\epsilon}W^\top P_\alpha W + 2e^\top P_\alpha (F(x)-F(\hat{x}))$$
This is where I stopped. Suppose first that $F = 0$. We would get, then, for $\alpha > \epsilon$,
$$ V(t) \leq V(0)\exp^{(-\alpha+\epsilon)t} + \frac{1}{\epsilon(-\alpha+\epsilon)}W^\top P_\alpha W$$
I thought initially that by increasing $\alpha$, we could decrease the term
$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon(-\alpha+\epsilon)}W^\top P_\alpha W $$
and thus making $e$ converge to a ball of any desired radius by an appropriate choice of $\alpha$. However, $P_\alpha$ depends on $\alpha$. What if by increasing $\alpha$ (by changing the gain $L$) the largest eigenvalue of $P_\alpha$ increases? That's the first point where I'm stuck: can we make that term that depends on $W$ arbitrarily small by an appropriate choice of $\alpha$ and $P_\alpha$ ?
Then, I tried to look at the case where $F\neq 0$. My intuition is that, if $\alpha$ is sufficiently large compared to the Lipschitz constant associated with $F(x(0))-F(\hat{x}(0))$, then things should be fine. I don't know however how to convert this intuition to a formal proof.
Thank you in advance for your help
